# Python - NameError: global name 'plus' is not defined

Tags: python, programming, python3

So I am creating a program using shelve and I keep getting this error message. I can not for the life of me figure it out and google hasn't been much help. Is this a problem with Ubuntu/Python working together, or an error in my program?

'plus' is the name of my shelve file and I am trying to open a new shelve file to write to.

Here's my IDLE console screen when it dies:

`Traceback (most recent call last):` 
  `File "/media/Windows-XP-Pro/Python32/Scripts/plu.py", line 217, in <module>
    start()` 
  `File "/media/Windows-XP-Pro/Python32/Scripts/plu.py", line 147, in start
    end()               # Go to the end() definition` 
  `File "/media/Windows-XP-Pro/Python32/Scripts/plu.py", line 110, in end
    dPLU = shelve.open(plus)` 
`NameError: global name 'plus' is not defined`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 99,9% of programming problems are your own code, not the programming language. That said, your problem is that `plus` is outside the namespace you're trying to call it in. Make sure you either defined `plus` or the function you're calling it in has access to it. Post the entire code on some Pastebin if possible if you need more specific help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'plus' is the name of the file, then the line should probably be:

```
dPLU = shelve.open('plus')
```

In other words, a string needs to be passed in, but as it is it looks like a variable (that is not defined yet) is being passed in.